# Is there any way to tell when an SVG animation is complete?

Tags: html, svg, raphael

I'm using the Raphael library to draw some shapes, and then animate them into view within the browser.

Is there any way I can check when one of these animations is complete in order to then trigger another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found an answer to this question, so will post for the reference of others.

Here is what I found: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/

A callback function can be added as an argument, as detailed in chapter 6 of the above article.